# Is it possible to use the verb "torture" in a figurative sense?

Tags: word-usage, metaphors

Is it possible to use the verb "torture" in a tropical sense? I mean not in a physical sense.

For example:

> Linda: "So what? Did you see Jack?"
>
> Tom: "Yes"
>
> Linda: "So did you talk to him about Betty?"
>
> Tom: "Well, he even met with Betty tonight himself"
>
> Linda: "He saw Betty tonight! So, did they arrive at any conclusion?"
>
> Tom: "Well, yes. They even called the office and received some
>   additional information"
>
> Linda: "What kind of additional information?"
>
> Tom: "Well, I would say super important information. Not only so, but
>   I myself on my way here found out something even more important"
>
> Linda: "Tell me everything"
>
> Tom: " Well, can I have a cup of tea first?"
>
> Linda: "Oh Tom, don't **torture** me like this"

Addition:

I used the word "tropical" here because the other day I was reading a book written by one Christian expositor (he died only in 1957) who was interpreting some versus from the New Testament in that book. He said there that some words in the scripture must be taken in their literal meaning, and some - only in their tropical meaning. Since he died only in 1957, I thought that using the word "tropical" in this way would still be okay in the modern English.

Also, while I was asking this question I had no idea that "torture" could imply only psychological sufferings. I thought it referred only to physical pain inflicted on someone by someone else in order to get some desired results (like getting some information from the one who is being tortured, some confession, etc.)

Comment: What do you mean by *tropical?*

Comment: You can definitely use *torture* in this sense. But as @FumbleFingers says, I don't believe that you can use *tropical* in this sense.

Comment: Presumably OP means *metaphorical* as opposed to *literal*. I can see how someone might (mistakenly) use *physical* for the second one, but why *tropical?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Perhaps it is supposed to be derived from *trope*. From the OED: *1862 H. Spencer First Princ. xv. (1875) 349 These [writings] had been partially differentiated into the kuriological or imitative, and the **tropical** or symbolic.* Sounds a bit outdated to me.

Comment: @Cerberus: Even figurative is a stretch. Emotional torture can still be torture. It's more about hyperbole, IMO.

Comment: @Robusto: Emotional torture is still technically a metaphor, I'd say. From *torqueo*, "to turn, wrench". But, yeah, hyperbole is probably what he's wondering about.

Comment: @Cer: Well, are you saying that waterboarding is not actual torture, since it may not involve turning or wrenching? That's an awfully narrow definition.

Comment: @Robusto: Eh our discussing this both in chat and here is a bit confusing. For posterity, I'd like to say that "primary" torture for me involves physical pain, and that emotional torture is or once was a metaphor for causing emotional pain in a similar way. A common metaphor is not literary at all: we use them all the time, like *see* in *I don't see why I should do what you say*. But yeah, once a metaphor becomes so common, it is hardly relevant to call it a metaphor any more.

Comment: This use of *tropical* is in the OED, but it hasn't been used in this form very much :  `4. Pertaining to, involving, or of the nature of a trope or tropes; metaphorical, figurative.`

Comment: This use of *tropical* seems to be used mainly in Bible studies, where many commenters say there are three ways of interpreting things: the *literal;* the *tropical, figurative* or *metaphorical;* and the *spiritual* or *mystical.* Outside of Bible studies, the word *figurative* or *metaphorical* should be used for this.

Comment: @simchona: No - it's just that you posted while I was writing my comment. To be honest, I'm not really keen on the word "trope" itself, since I think all it does better than "metaphor" is make you sound a bit more intellectual/academic. [Here's](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=trope%2Cmetaphor&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) my evidence that "trope" isn't particularly common, anyway.

Comment: Little Timmy says his Mom tortures him by serving tofu for dinner!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure the tropical sense that you refered to, but this is more of an emotional torture that the passage refers to.

Torture is prolonged (possibly intentional infliction of) pain, so she's saying that not knowing is hurting her. Because Tom is waiting to have tea first, she's accusing him of intentionally prolonging the pain of not knowing the info.

Note that this is definitely a jest and nothing close to what you'd consider a real physical POW-style torture.  She is simply trying to get him to hurry up...

Comment: What is "POW-style"?

Comment: @brilliant. I think POW stands for prisoner of war.

Comment: Of course, torture of prisoners of war is forbidden under international law so that's not a great way to say it. Maybe "medieval-style"